# Blender animation to UNITY

Tags: animation, unity

Im sort of new to blender and i have made a animation that has something disappearing half way through the animation like so-[image: catapult flinging a rock and going back to resting position]

I created the disappearing rock affect by key framing the eyeball in the top right of blender [image]

When i ported it over to unity though i get the full animation with the rock still there! How do i go about fixing this issue thanks!

Comment: Viewport visibility is a Blender specific property, it can't most likely be exported, and must be animated in Unity. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's best to just make this animation in Unity itself. How did you import this animation to unity? Legacy? Was the rock animated seperately? if it was, you could add a script to it, that plays the animation and then destroys the rock gameobject, or you could make an animation in unity and make the gameObject invisible.
one way of coding that in C#:

```
    Transform.Find("Rock").gameObject.enabled = false;
```

or, if you've made a prefab of the rock, you could just destroy it, and spawn it again if you need it:

```
    Destroy(Transform.Find("Rock"));
```